# I can't get PUT to work in Spring Data REST

Tags: rest, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I am trying to learn Spring Data REST but I got stuck immediately. I have two entities, User and Event. A User have a one-to-many relationship with Event, so a User can have many Events.

```
@Entity
public class {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Event> events;
...
}
```

I have a corresponding UserRepository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    ApplicationUser findByUsername(String username);
}
```

When I start the project it expose several endpoints, and I tried this

```
GET http://localhost:8080/api/users/1/events
```

And it works, I get this

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "events": []
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/applicationUsers/1/events"
        }
    }
}
```

Then I tried to add an event

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/api/users/1/events (with a payload of course)
```

And then send the GET request for events again, but it is still empty. And it doesn't seem to have been any inserts.

Should this work by default in Spring Data REST or am I missing something? I assumed that a Set annotated with @OneToMany should give me the possibility to add an Event to a certain User.

Answer (score 0):

There are two forms of resources in spring-data-rest.

- [collection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.collection-resource) (ex: /events)
- [item](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.item-resource) (ex: /events/1)

In spring-data-rest [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.collection-resource), it clearly mentions that for a collection resource, it only supports

- GET
- POST

only. (Other than HEAD).

So in your **"/events"** (a collection resource) resource, there's **no PUT** endpoint.

You may do it via a custom endpoint with a custom query. (not a built in endpoint)